# I need a stored procedure that gives out put of matched patterns against a string in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

There is a column in a table which contains many patterns.
I need a query that takes one string as input and will give all the patterns from that table column that match that string as output.

Say in Pattern table column1 there are values like `ab%,a%c%,%1%,k%`.
Now,I will give abcd12 as input string to my query and it will give output as

```
ab%
a%c%
%1%
```

but it will not give k% as output, because it is not a pattern that matches for exact string abcd12.

I believe it can be done using stored procedure. 
Can you guys please help me.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not really regex but SQL pattern like in your examples then you can simply select it:

```
SELECT pattern FROM patterns WHERE 'abcd12' LIKE pattern
```

Comment: [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1387d/1). Easy to wrap that in a procedure but I'm not sure there'd be much point.